# Strange wordpress GET request

Tags: wordpress, apache, get, response, plesk

I've just upgraded to Wordpress 4.8 and in the waterfall overview I see something strange. It's a get request which is being called on any page of my website. It looks like this:

- http://www.my-website-url.com**/page/2** (SEE BOLD STUFF)
- it's 0kb but is adds a loadingtime of 400ms.
- Response headers:
  [image: response header]

Any Idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `X-Moz: prefetch` header indicates that this is Firefox prefetching the next page. Your software of choice probably has a `<link>` element 
or similar that indicates content that the browser might want to prefetch for faster loading if the user decides to navigate there. It shouldn't cause any delay in displaying the initial page as prefetching is only done after the page itself has finished loading. Also, I don't know where the 0Kb came from as the `Content-Length` header states it's about 10kB big.

For more information about Firefox's implementation of link prefetching, see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ

Comment: Wow that's new for me. Thanks! Is there any way to disable prefetching? Should this be done serverside?

Comment: You are completely right. I've found the <link> element you're talking about:
<link rel="next" href="http://www.xxxx.nl/page/2/">

I'll try to find out how to get rid of it because there is really no need to prefetch page 2.

Comment: ALL IN ONE SEO is the wordpress plugin which adds the  <link rel="next" href="xxxx.nl/page/2/">. 


This appears to be the answer why I the difference between the page views and the unique visitors was so big.

Comment: I had to change the ALL IN ONE SEO plugin to fix this.